# Calculating and displaying the days ago

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in the format `2015-09-24T00:03:13+05:30`. I want to calculate how many days have passed since that particular date and display as " x days ago". Is there any easy solution for this?

Comment: Easiest solution: use `momentjs` and the `fromNow` method

Comment: Before you ask, you have to try something by your own. Share the *code*, you have tried. And then we'll help you!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Moment.js

```
call moment(' your datetime ').fromNow();
```

Here's the link http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

First slice the string and get day

```
  var prevstr = "2015-09-24T00:03:13+05:30";
  var prevday = str.slice(8,10);//gets 24 from the above string.
  var nowstr = Date();//get todays date
  var nowday = str.slice(8,10);//gets todays
  var a = parseInt(prevday);
  var b = parseInt(nowday);
  var result = b-a;
  alert(result+"days ago");
```

But It works only if they are in same month.

Comment: your code will display days in negative if current date gets above 24.

Comment: Its just an example how you can achive what you want with out using moment.js . I hope this gives you an Idea of what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it using Date.parse() function and a bit of Maths. The idea is to convert current date and the date I want in milliseconds, calculating their difference and then converting the difference in days. Thanks you all for your help. :)